# On sketching an equivalent circuit

Tags: diodes

[image]

Given a circuit like the one on the picture, I am very confused on how to reduce it to a simpler form(I do it because at this point I am more comfortable with solving circuits which  are all in *one piece*, meaning all the conductors are connected graphically). However, for this diagram I am unsure how to do it. I did reduce it to a simpler form, but I guess it can be done much better since the way I did it the Iteration method for solving the diodes would be quite a mess.
The way I tried to simplify it:
[image]
Now from the diagram of mine it is easy to guess which of the diodes is in forward bias and which one is not. Is my correction alright?

Comment: The circuit on the diagram is already very simple. But generally, the "simplified" form will depend on what exactly you want to calculate, such that this value won't get "merged" with others during the simplification process.

Comment: I will post a picture of a circuit I drew shortly. I tried to make as not to change the balance in the circuit.

Comment: @EugeneSh. There, I added the jpeg file in the question.

Comment: Actually it doesn't look like simplification to me. Do you want a way of solving this specific circuit? In general, denote every junction with a voltage variable, every branch with a current, write some equations and solve them. In this circuit you need the iteration only for D1, since the others the biasing is straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

The original schematic has an error in it, where D3 is called out twice:

[image]

Fixing that yields:

[image]

With +5V connected to GND through R3 and D3, D3 will be forward biased and there'll be about 0.7 volts across it, which puts the anode of D1 at about 0.7 volts, as well.

Then, with the 10 volt supply connected to R1 and D2, R1D1 will be reverse biased by about 9.3 volts and, since no charge will flow through them, they're effectively not in the circuit.

Re-annotating the schematic and explicitly showing the ground connection to the supplies yields this electrical simplification:

[image]